# GTX 1060 installation on GA-AX370 motherboard on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I have Ryzen 3 2200G with integrated graphics and when I connect the HDMI to the motherboard and change settings to integrated graphics in BIOS it boots correctly, but when I connect HDMI to the graphic card (ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1060) it asks for an encryption password, blinks for a while, and stops at the following screen.

[image: Freeze Screen]

How do I solve it? I don't think there should be a problem with my partitions because it wouldn't boot in Integrated Graphics use case and I tried flipping the switch use_lvmetad from 1 to 0, but still this shows up. Please point me in the direction where I should think?

Also I have installed the Nvidia drivers. My kernel version is 4.15.0-43 and Nvidia drivers installed are at version 410.

Dual BIOS and secure boot do not seem to be the problems.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: @Terrance There's no explicit secure boot option but these are the settings
CSM Support : Enabled
Other PCI Device ROM Priority : UEFI Only
Storage Boot Option Control : Legacy Only

I'm having a feeling of flipping PCI to Legacy?!

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with flipping the PCI Switch to Legacy, facing the same problem

Comment: That's right, these are Dual BIOS boards.  Same thing I got for my sons computers.  My bad!  I think there is a BIOS setting to set the PCI to primary video instead of the on-board one.

Comment: _caissalover_, comments will soon scroll off the screen, Instead of replying with a Comment, please instead click [edit] and enhance your original question with the new info, then click on (x) at the end of each comment and delete the Comments once their data's in your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled Ubuntu. Guess there was some sort of mounting error with encryption. Not an optimal solution but tremendously practical. Took 20 mins after banging my head since last 40 hours. Backed up using Integrated graphics boot and reinstalled OS!

Thanks everyone!